# Pure SSH2 client with xterm.js

Tags: xtermjs

I was wondering if it's possible to create a pure SSH2 client using just javascript (xterm.js) without using some sort of server based proxy.

All the examples I see so far seems to require some sort of server (nodejs based or in a couple of cases PHP).  I'm wondering if it's possible to just go straight from the browser to the ssh server using a client like xterm.js.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: you cannot open a raw tcp connection from a web page

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know that. I guess in some ways that makes sense - security and all.

Comment: Should still be possible with https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge and a dumb relay proxy just forwarding the stream chunks. But then you have the ssh client solely in a webpage, which creates new headache to properly secure passwords/ssh keys provided to that webpage. Could be done with SRI, but prolly not worth the trouble...